# DateTime.Today and "static readonly"

Tags: c#, .net

`DateTime.Today` is `static readonly`.  So supposedly it should never change once (statically) instantiated.

However -- if I fire up an application and ask for the date at 11:59pm and then again at 12:01am, it will correctly give me different values each time i call it, right?

Let's say I wanted to create a `static readonly` "`DateTime.TwoDaysFromNow`" (just a representative example) that behaves the same way.  .NET will tell me I can't b/c it's a `readonly` remember!  How can I make it work?

Much appreciated,
-Alan.

Comment: Technically, it is a [read-only property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (not *readonly*), since it only declares a `get` accessor.  It is not declared using the `readonly` modifier, since `readonly` can only be applied to fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static DateTime TwoDaysFromNow
{
    get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(2); }
}
```

You can tell `DateTime.Today` is a property from Microsoft's Syntax of it:

> public static DateTime Today { get; }

Comment: Static properties, huh? Brilliant!  I'll accept it in 10 minutes, it won't let me before then.

Comment: @Alan take your time, maybe somebody will come up with a more descriptive answer by then.

Answer (score 7):

It's a static readonly property, not a static readonly field:

```
public static DateTime Today
{
    get
    {
        return Now.Date;
    }
}
```